# How to access parent and matched children object with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to get parent object value and all the childs who has ischecked flag true with lodash.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
responsetable = [{
  "Qty": 3,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked":true
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 50,
  "lineItemQty": 3,
},
]


const filter = _.filter(this.responsetable, function (item) {
 return  _.some(item.List2, { 'ischecked': true });
});

console.dir(filter)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

here from this json i want to check which all children has ischecked true only those children i want to display with object value.
This is what i have tried so far but its returning me all the serial number objects not the one which has ischecked flag set to true

from this json i want qty ,lineitemid and lineitemqty along with matched child.
Expected output is

```
   [{
    "Qty": 3,
    "List1": [],
    "List2": [

      {
        "serialNumber": "2",
         "ischecked":true;
      },
    ],
    "lineItemId": 50,
    "lineItemQty": 3,
  },
  ]
```

Comment: can you just post the expected output

Comment: I have posted please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need lodash for this. `filter` `map` and `some` are all built into javascript.

It is not particularly easy from your question to know exactly what you need, but here is a best guess if you want to only take those objects which have at least one `ischecked` value in one of their lists:

```js
const responsetable = [{
  "Qty": 3,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked":true 
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 50,
  "lineItemQty": 3,
},
{
  "Qty": 5,
  "List1": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":true
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "List2": [
    
  ],
  "lineItemId": 51,
  "lineItemQty": 100,
}
]

const listHasACheckedSerial = list => list.some(listItem => listItem.ischecked)

const getResponseObjectLists = responseObject => Object.keys(responseObject)
  .filter(key => key.indexOf('List') > -1)
  .map(key => responseObject[key])

const responseObjectHasCheckedList = responseObjectIn => getResponseObjectLists(responseObjectIn)
  .map(list => listHasACheckedSerial(list))
  .some(v => !!v)

const getRequiredResponseObjectProperties = responseObject => ({
  Qty: responseObject.Qty,
  List1: responseObject.List1.filter(item => item.ischecked),
  List2: responseObject.List2.filter(item => item.ischecked),
  lineItemId: responseObject.lineItemId,
  lineItemQty: responseObject.lineItemQty,
})

const filter = responseObjects => responseObjects
  .filter(responseObject => responseObjectHasCheckedList(responseObject))
  .map(responseObject => getRequiredResponseObjectProperties(responseObject))

const test = getResponseObjectLists(responsetable[0])
const result = filter(responsetable)

console.dir(result)
```

However if you only want to check items in `List2`:

```js
const responsetable = [{
  "Qty": 3,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked":true 
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 50,
  "lineItemQty": 3,
},
{
  "Qty": 5,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 51,
  "lineItemQty": 100,
}
]

const getRequiredResponseObjectProperties = responseObject => ({
  Qty: responseObject.Qty,
  List1: responseObject.List1.filter(item => item.ischecked),
  List2: responseObject.List2.filter(item => item.ischecked),
  lineItemId: responseObject.lineItemId,
  lineItemQty: responseObject.lineItemQty,
})

const filter = responseObjects => responseObjects
  .filter(r => r.List2
    .map(l => l.ischecked)
    .some(v => !!v)
  )
  .map(r => getRequiredResponseObjectProperties(r))
  
console.dir(filter(responsetable))
```

Comment: Is there any simple solution with lodash?

Comment: It depends what you want - do you want to take all objects in responsetable, and for each object, remove items from List2 which have ischecked as false?

Comment: You don't really need lodash if you're just using `filter` `map` and `some`

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work..

```js
let responsetable  = [{
  "Qty": 3,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [
    {
      "serialNumber": "1",
       "ischecked":false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
       "ischecked":true
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
       "ischecked":false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 50,
  "lineItemQty": 3,
},
]

for(var i=0; i<responsetable.length; i++){
  // checking whether List1 is empty or not
  if(responsetable[i].List1.length > 0){
    responsetable[i].List1 = responsetable[i].List1.filter((o) =>{
    return o.ischecked
  })
  }

  responsetable[i].List2 = responsetable[i].List2.filter((o) =>{
    return o.ischecked
  })
}

console.log(responsetable)
```

Comment: But i want parent object value as well as i mentioned in my question

Comment: This is not what i want to display

Comment: i have updated the answer please check , Let me know whether it worked for you

Comment: i didnt understand, i hope List1 is an empty array . Also the question was to check in List2 isn't

Comment: @Uidev123 Not working getting list1 as well ?? do you need to check on the list1 too. can you just post the entire sample data and expected output. Based on the question i hope the solution works

Comment: Sometime list1 its empty

Comment: i have update the code. please check the answer and let me know whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in a very concise way is with `_.map/_.mapValues/_.filter`:

```
_.map(data, (x) => _.mapValues(x, (y) => _.isArray(y) ? _.filter(y, (k) => k.ischecked === true) : y))
```

Full code with the data:

```js
var data = [{
  "Qty": 3,
  "List1": [],
  "List2": [{
      "serialNumber": "1",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "2",
      "ischecked": true
    },
    {
      "serialNumber": "3",
      "ischecked": false
    }
  ],
  "lineItemId": 50,
  "lineItemQty": 3,
}]

var result = _.map(data, (x) => _.mapValues(x, (y) => _.isArray(y) ? _.filter(y, (k) => k.ischecked === true) : y))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```